# Reidemeister Moves

Tags: knot-theory

In knot theory, two links are equivalent if and only if they can be deformed from one to another by performing a finite number of Reidemeister moves. But sometimes it is so confusing that I don't know which type move should I perform on link to get desired result. Is there any procedure so that we can always get the desired result provided we know that the two links are equivalent?

Also, is there any computer software which deals with Reidemeister moves? Because sometimes I find it is very difficult to visualise the link after some Reidemeister moves.

Comment: This has been answered and accepted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/147112/5687